# Google Apps Script: Responding to a pre-existing email thread

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I've put together a library checkout system that I'd like to automatically reply on the original checkout thread, that their borrowed items are overdue past the due date.

I've done some research and testing, but have run into a roadblock regarding how Gmail thread ID's are exposed in the API. I've gathered all the relevant borrower data into our checkout spreadsheet, and was ready to store the thread ID obtained from a

```
var foundThread = GmailApp.search('from:me to:jon.doe@company.com,jane.doe@company.com MEDIA CHECKOUT XXXXXXX');
var threadID = foundThread[0];
Logger.log(threadID); //check
```

into a column, but was disappointed to discover it wasn't stored as an identifiable string, but a GmailThread object instead. Is there a way to extract unique thread identifiers from this within Google Apps Script that is usable for my purposes? I wanted to avoid referencing just the GmailApp.search() query you see above to avoid hits on similarly Subject-titled emails of an unrelated checkout request (will happen); hence my love for the unique thread ID identifier.

Is there a better way to go about this? Like storing the GmailThread object in a persistent array somewhere? Or am I stuck with searching just by recipients and subject titles?

Comment: `var foundThread = GmailApp.search('from:me to:jon.doe@company.com,jane.doe@company.com MEDIA CHECKOUT XXXXXXX');
var threadID = foundThread[0];
Logger.log(threadID.getId()); //check` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread

Comment: @Cooper can't believe I missed that entry. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For documentation purposes, as a user posted in the comments, you were logging the GmailThread object itself instead of the identifier which is what you want, you can get the Id by applying the `getId` method [1] to the GmailThread object. The code ends up like this:

```
var foundThread = GmailApp.search('from:me to:jon.doe@company.com,jane.doe@company.com MEDIA CHECKOUT XXXXXXX');
var threadID = foundThread[0];
Logger.log(threadID.getId()); //check
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getid

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. And another little addendum here to close it out since I wasn't able to find it anywhere else and it might be helpful to others trying to do the same, re-retrieving the thread by ID if it wasn't saved

```
var threadID = thread.getId();
...
var thrd = GmailApp.getThreadById(threadID);
thrd.replyAll(msg);
```